# How can I read code from imported angular modules in vs-code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

If I [ctrl]-click a type in vs-code, I can see for example the following "code" (from a compiled angular class/module ...):

```
export declare class Record extends HashMap {
    readonly id: number;
    constructor(id: number);
}

export declare class HashMap {
    /**
     * Get the value from associated key
     * @param key Key
     */
    getData<T>(key: string): T;
}
```

Generally: How can I read/understand this? I mean, it seems like a lot of information is missing here.
I can understand that there is HashMap created ok, but generally this kind of "code" seems to be incomplete.
What is the constructor exactly doing? It gets a number... ok... and HashMap has a getData Method, which gives me some generic type back.

So, like `new Record(24)` is creating something? But not really a key => value data pair regarding to this codepieces here or?
HashMap doesnt seem to have a property where `getData` is working on... neither does `Record` have this.
How can I know which model Im getting back when my method has return value of type `Record`?

Answer (score 0):

What you see is "just" the code declaration file (**declaring** all available methods and types), not actual code that is executed. Probably the file ending of the opened file is `.d.ts` to indicate that it is the declaration file.

For more information on the topic [read here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).